# Show div with same data value on click and hide all others

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have list of items in ,UL, LI items, each li have a particular data attribute value. What I want is on clicking of each li item, another div which have same data-attribue need to show, ever other div should hide.

Example if I click on li with data-value= "devops", div which contain data-attribute="devops", should be visible and others should hide.

Following is my API code, you can just run that directly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <?php
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.recruitee.com/c/1832/offers?scope=active",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer R0tYYXBTWG1Ddm5wbUgzT3pwa214Zz09"
        ),
        ));
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
        curl_close($curl);
?>

<?php

  $grouped_jobs = array();
  $grouped_locations = array();

   foreach($response->offers as $key=>$value){
      $grouped_jobs[$value->department][] = array('title'=> $value->title, 'location'=> $value->location, 'url'=> $value->url);

   }

   foreach ($grouped_jobs as $key=>$value) {
    foreach ($value as $job) {

        array_push($grouped_locations, $job['location']);
       }
    }
   ?>

<div class="job_filter">
    <ul class="dept_filter">
        <?php foreach($grouped_jobs as $key=>$value){ ?>
       <li class="departments" data-value="<?php echo $key;  ?>"><?php echo $key;  ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>


<ul class="loct_filter">
<?php foreach(array_unique(array_map("ucfirst", $grouped_locations) ) as $loc){  ?>
<li class="locations"> <?php echo $loc;  ?>   </li>
<?php }?>
</ul>

</div>


<?php
   
   foreach($grouped_jobs as $key=>$value){

    echo '<div class="job_detailed" data-department='.$key.'>
         <h1><u>'.$key.'</u></h1> <br>';
         foreach($value as $job) {
             echo '<p>'.$job['title'].'</p><br>
         <p>'.$job['location'].'</p>
         <a target="_blank" href='.$job['url'].'>Read More </a>';
    
     }
     echo '</div>';  
}

?>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( '.departments' ).click(function(index) {
           var data_value = $(this).data('value');
           console.log(data_value);
         
           if($(this).data('department') == data_value) {
               $(this).hide();
           }
       });

       // For the mammal value
});
</script>
</html>
```

Where is the error in my jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can first hide all `job_detailed` divs then simply use  `$(".job_detailed[data-department=" + data_value + "]").show()` to show only div which has same value as li which is clicked.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.departments').click(function(index) {
    $('.dept_filter > li').not(this).removeClass("active")
    $(this).addClass("active")
    show_hide(); //call fn

  });
  $('.locations').click(function(index) {
    $('.loct_filter > li').not(this).removeClass("active")
    $(this).addClass("active")
    show_hide(); //call fn
  });
});

function show_hide() {
  //check if location li is  has active class
  var locs = $(".locations.active").length > 0 ? $(".locations.active").text() : " ";
  //check if dept li has active class or not 
  var data_value = $(".departments.active").length > 0 ? $(".departments.active").attr("data-value") : " ";
  $(".job_detailed").hide(); //hide all divs
  if ((data_value != " ") && (locs != " ")) {
    //check if p tag has location and then get closest div show it
    $(".loc:contains(" + locs + ")").closest(".job_detailed[data-department=" + data_value + "]").show()
  } else if (locs != " ") {
    //if only loc is slected get closest div show it
    $(".loc:contains(" + locs + ")").closest(".job_detailed").show()
  } else if (data_value != " ") {
    //if only dept is selected show that
    $(".job_detailed[data-department=" + data_value + "]").show()
  }


}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="job_filter">
  <h5>Department : </h5>
  <ul class="dept_filter">

    <li class="departments" data-value="A">
      A
    </li>
    <li class="departments" data-value="B">
      B
    </li>
    <li class="departments" data-value="C">
      C
    </li>
    <li class="departments" data-value="D">
      D
    </li>

  </ul>
  <h5> Location :</h5>
  <ul class="loct_filter">
    <li class="locations">aa</li>
    <li class="locations">sss</li>
    <li class="locations">mno</li>
    <li class="locations">xyz</li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="job_detailed" data-department='A'>
  <h1><u>A</u></h1> <br>

  <p>something</p><br>
  <p>ABC</p>
  <a target="_blank" href=''>Read More </a>

</div>
<div class="job_detailed" data-department='A'>
  <h1><u>A</u></h1> <br>

  <p>something</p><br>
  <!--added loc class to location-->
  <p class="loc">abc</p>
  <a target="_blank" href=''>Read More </a>
  <p class="loc">xyz</p>
  <a target="_blank" href=''>Read More </a>
  <p class="loc">mno</p>
  <a target="_blank" href=''>Read More </a>

</div>
<div class="job_detailed" data-department='A'>
  <h1><u>A</u></h1> <br>

  <p>something</p><br>
  <p class="loc">xyz</p>
  <a target="_blank" href=''>Read More </a>

</div>
<div class="job_detailed" data-department='D'>
  <h1><u>D</u></h1> <br>

  <p>something</p><br>
  <p class="loc">mno</p>
  <a target="_blank" href=''>Read More </a>

</div>
<div class="job_detailed" data-department='C'>
  <h1><u>C</u></h1> <br>

  <p>something</p><br>
  <p class="loc">sss</p>
  <a target="_blank" href=''>Read More </a>

</div>
<div class="job_detailed" data-department='D'>
  <h1><u>D</u></h1> <br>

  <p>something</p><br>
  <p class="loc">aa</p>
  <a target="_blank" href=''>Read More </a>

</div>
<div class="job_detailed" data-department='B'>
  <h1><u>B</u></h1> <br>

  <p>something</p><br>
  <p class="loc">aa</p>
  <a target="_blank" href=''>Read More </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, I found 2 problems here, one thing is pls click on product development or web development, filter is not showing properly

Another one is if you click on locations , then also it should be filtered based on that department value

Comment: where is `product development or web development..` ? Also inside `p` tag you are printing location ?

Comment: I have updated my code check if thats what you need .